# FAB from design support library does not move upward when snackbar is shown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-design-library

[This post](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) says:

> When you add a `FloatingActionButton` as a child of your
>   `CoordinatorLayout` and then pass that `CoordinatorLayout` to your
>   `Snackbar.make()` call - instead of the snackbar displaying over the
>   floating action button, the `FloatingActionButton` ... automatically
>   move upward as the snackbar animates in and returns to its position
>   when the snackbar animates out

I've made exactly as described there but FAB does not move upward. (Snackbar can be swiped out, it means that CoordinatorLayout knows about it.)

**Upd**

Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/action_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.ActionBar"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/action_toolbar"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/theme_primary_darker_color"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_action_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_navigation_white_24dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/action_toolbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Code:

```
mCoordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_content);
...
Snackbar.make(mCoordinatorLayout, R.string.waypoint_deleted, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Post the code of your layout and Activity, please.

Comment: Well, not the full Activity, I mean the place where you call the Snackbar.make() method.

Answer (score 8):

I've written sample project based on the code you posted and I had to change three things to make `FloatingActionButton` aware of the `Snackbar`.

1. Set 'minifyEnabled' property of my build to `false` - looks like Proguard strips out some annotations (e.g. `Behaviour`s) which are necessary to coordinate `FloatingActionButton`. You'll need to add some Proguard rules in your release build where Proguard is enabled.
2. Pass the `FloatingActionButton` as a first argument of `Snackbar.make()`, not the `CoordinatorLayout` itself as mentioned [here](https://lab.getbase.com/introduction-to-coordinator-layout-on-android/).
3. Remove `app:layout_anchor="@id/action_toolbar"` and replace `app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"` with the `app:layout_gravity="bottom|right|end"` from the layout (not sure if it's suitable for you).

If it doesn't work for you, you can try to write your own `Behavior` class as described in the article mentioned above.

Comment: I'm getting `Error:(84) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_gravity' in package 'com.mycompany.myapp`

Comment: rather than setting minifyEnabled, you can also add this to your proguard.flags file:

`-keep class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton$* { *; }`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where my fab button wouldn't move down. Took me a while but it was because I had animations off in the developers option. Hope you got it working even though I know this post is a bit dated.

Comment: That was just what worked for me didn't mean to say it was the only answer. In my situation this is what happened

Answer (score 0):

I was having the issue where the fab would not return to its original location after the snackbar disappeared. Make sure **Animator duration scale** is turned on. A good default is 1x.

The setting can be found in:

1. Settings app --> Developer Options
2. Dev Settings app (on emulators)

This setting along with other animation settings were turned off on one of my emulators. Turning it back on got the fab working correctly.